# SQL SET value to 0, weekly

Tags: php, sql

I have a question regarding setting a value in my database to 0 weekly. The value is an integer that counts +1 multiple times each day depending on user actions. But after the week ends the value needs to be set to 0 again.

How can this be done in a combination with SQL and PHP - have hard time finding any documentation for this?

Comment: `UPDATE table SET field = 0`? Or what?

Comment: @u_mulder I think the question is how schedule that to happen every week.

Comment: Hehe I can set a table to 0 ;) - It needs to be done weekly.

Comment: Use a DB `event` The implementation depends on your DB engine

Comment: Does your webserver have phpmyadmin? There is a scheduler function there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) event (sample below):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT my_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' WEEK
STARTS '2015-09-04 12:00:00'
DO 
BEGIN
 UPDATE YOUR_TABLE SET YOUR_FIELD = 0;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Start cron on server every week whith query

```
UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = 0;
```